# Rails - Joining 4 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let say we have 4 tables

```
Client has many Campaign
Campaign has many Adgroup
Adgroup has many Ad
Ad
```

The relationship is the same, one to many. Let say we have known Ad.id, and we want to get Client.id from that Ad.id.

Could anybody give an elegant solution (by elegant i mean without writing sql statement, instead use active records procedure)?

Comment: client_id = ad.adgroup.campaign.client.client_id ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Ad `belongs_to` an Adgroup, and has a reference to it in it's db structure! Adgroups should `belongs_to` Campaigns and so on, all the way up. Remember, the dude with `belongs_to` is the one that needs to hold a reference in his db table to the guy that `has_one` him, not the other way round!

If the resources are created OK to begin with, you should be able to call `@ad.adgroup.campaign.client.id` and get a particular ad's (obtained, say, by `@ad = Ad.find(some_id)`) id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, this is also what first came up on mind, but i read somewhere that its not a good practice. It run slow and eat resource. I was loking for solution with :joins parameter, but dont know how to do it in rails without query.

Comment: Well, from what I know, since you're creating that relationship in the model, rails will do the joins in the background anyway, so I don't really see a problem with this code...

Answer (score 1):

With Rails associations, you have to remember to specify `belongs_to` for the other side of the relationship, so an ad will most likely `has_one Adgroup` and so on and so forth up the chain. Once you've coupled the associations, you can use ActiveRecord to method chain these models starting from the bottom, going up to the top of the hierarchy. So you would start with ad and chain it like:

```
@ad = Ad.find(an_id_or_name_or_whatever).Adgroup.Campaign.Client.id
```

Looking at the above, you can chain the `Adgroup` onto an `Ad` because of the associative relationship which gives you access to the methods of that parent model, all the way up to the `Client` model, of which `.id` is a method, and you can call it.

Take a look at some association basics from Rails here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have your relationships setup as follows:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad_group, inverse_of: :ads
end

class AdGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign, inverse_of: :ad_groups
  has_many :ads, inverse_of :ad_group
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, inverse_of: :campaigns
  has_many :ad_groups, inverse_of :campaign
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns, inverse_of :client
end
```

Use joins and pluck if all you want is the client id and efficient SQL:

```
Client.joins(campaigns: {ad_groups: :ad}).where(
  ads: { id: some_id }).pluck('clients.id').first
```

If you want the entire client and efficient SQL then just:

```
Client.joins(campaigns: {ad_groups: :ad}).where(ads: { id: some_id }).first
```